# How to search in a string for the date between dateFrom and dateTo

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, substring, between

I have three parameters, **$motivazione**, **$dateFrom** and **$dateTo**, in my table I have the following string: **{"motivation": 17, "dfp": "31/10/2022"}**

The query must return the id of the row if the string in the db contains motivazione: $motivazione and dfp: between dateFrom and dateTo,

with the following query I can only get the date contained in the string:

`SELECT column,  SUBSTRING (column, CHARINDEX ('dfp', column) +6, 10) FROM myTable`

but I can't compare it

how can I do?

Thank you

Comment: If you have a json object stored in a SQL column, you could use JSON_VALUE (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of doing fragile SubString. Your query would look like: select column, JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.dfp') as dfp from myTable - you would have to convert varchar to date to do any comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your date string to a SQL Server date: `CONVERT(DATE,'31/10/2022', 103)`.

The format 103 is `dd/mm/yyyy`. If you don't specify it, the date might be interpreted in the US format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Also, if you have a JSON string, use @AnthonyG's advice to extract the date value.

A where clause would be something like this

```sql
WHERE CONVERT(JSON_VALUE(Data, '$.dfp'), 103) BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-01-31'
```

Use the year first format for date literals, then you will not have the dd/mm - mm/dd issue.